# I can't ping to a local docker container IP in server A from server B creating a static route

Tags: ip, routing, route, iproute

I’m trying to create a static route between two servers, server A and server B, 
I created the static route from server B to server A so I could ping to a docker container in server A.

**Server A details:**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 06:4e:7a:ff:c5:b8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.31.124.249/20 brd 172.31.127.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 2327sec preferred_lft 2327sec
    inet6 fe80::44e:7aff:feff:c5b8/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN 
    link/ether 02:42:7b:af:4d:e5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**Server B details:**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 06:35:26:6c:2d:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.31.126.46/20 brd 172.31.127.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 2729sec preferred_lft 2729sec
    inet6 fe80::435:26ff:fe6c:2d02/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**What did I do?**

I created that static ip route on server B with:

```
sudo ip route add 172.17.0.0/24 via 172.31.124.249 dev eth0
```

After that command the routing table is as follows:

```
ip route show
default via 172.31.112.1 dev eth0 
172.17.0.0/24 via 172.31.124.249 dev eth0 
172.31.112.0/20 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.31.126.46
```

When I try to ping the docker container in server A from server B I don't get any response:

```
 ping 172.17.0.1
PING 172.17.0.1 (172.17.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 172.17.0.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2999ms
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Did you add a route on server A so it knows how to reply?

Comment: I didn't add any route on server A. Could you please explain more on what you are saying? Thank you!

Comment: Communication is a two-way problem. Just because B knows the route to A, it doesn't mean that A knows the route to B. So A can't reply to the pings.

Comment: Are you saying that I need to add a new route from A to B or open ports in the firewall?

Comment: You need a route from A to B. And you have to allow ICMP through the firewall (there are no ports for ICMP).

Comment: I did this on my server A> `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -i eth0 -j ACCEPT` and still is not getting any response back when pinging.

Comment: Did you add the route? Or does its default route point to the appropriate router already?

Comment: You mean the route I already created in server B? Yes it's already there.

Comment: No, the route in A that I keep asking about. Ping is 2 way. B sends a message to A, then A has to send a response to B. If A doesn't have a route to B, it can't send the response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60152/discussion-between-vato-and-barmar).